# JavaScript global variables declaration

Tags: javascript, global-variables, variable-declaration

The following script works correctly although I need to make few amends. In each function I am getting the values need for the different formulas. However I tend to replicate the same line of code in different functions.

Ex.

```
function one(){ var v1= document.getElementById('one').value; }
function two(){ var v1= document.getElementById('one').value; }
```

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/qFjb7/)

I would like to declare all of the variables once and than only use the ones I need for the specific functions. If I declare them right at the top than once they are called they still hold the original value so I need to update that value to the current one if changed of course.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.  Are you asking how to create global variables?

Comment: Personally I would like to declare variable for *element* and fetch fetch its value when required. like `var v1= document.getElementById('one');` and use like `v1.value`

Comment: I am basically using the same variable value in different functions (Ex. v1= document.getElementById('one').value;), however I would like to declare all of the input values once and them use the variables in the functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be very hard to read if you do it like in your fiddle.

Instead do

```
var myVars;
window.onload=function() {
  myVars = { 
    'list_price': document.getElementById('list_price'),
    'negotiated': document.getElementById('negotiated'),
    .
    .
    'lease_payment': document.getElementById('lease_payment')
  }
```

now you can do

```
var price = myVars.list_price.value;
```

or perhaps add a function

```
function getVal(id) {
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (val =="" || isNaN(val)) return 0;
  return parsetInt(val,10); 
}
```

now you can do

```
var price = getVal("list_price");
```

Comment: All this is amazing, I like to see different solutions. Thank you

Comment: A small comment, I had to remove .value from "lease_payment" as it would return "undefined" when called like this: var x4 = myVars.lease_payment.value. Would you why?

Comment: I had a .value wrongly there. Removed now. Note the lack of comma after the last item in the object

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Update your variable when the value changes
2. Use a function that always returns the correct value

1) You can add a listener for the `change` event or the `keyup` event that changes your global variable:

```
// save initial value
var val = document.getElementById('one').value;

// update the value when input is changed
addEventListener(document.getElementById('one'), 'change', function() {
  val = document.getElementById('one').value;
});

console.log(val);
```

2) You can use a function that always returns the current value:

```
var val = function() { return document.getElementById('one').value; };

console.log(val());
```

2b) If you hate parenthesis, you can define a property that uses the function above as a getter:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'one', {
  get : function() { return document.getElementById('one').value; }
});

console.log(one);
```

Comment: What if value in the input box changed, v1 and v2 will still give old value, read the question carefully

Comment: @shadow very good point, especially that the input will change often as people might want to see different results (on the right) based on the new input values (on the left)

Answer (score 1):

mplungjan's solution is a great one. If you're at all concerned by your global vars leaking into the window scope, wrap your code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression to prevent that from happening:

```
(function(){
  // code goes here
}());
```